# Can a SHOW FIELDS query use ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql

The [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/extended-show.html) don't mention ORDER BY and I have had no luck phrasing this query:

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM `TB_Main`  WHERE Type = 'mediumtext' OR Type = 'bit(1)' ORDER BY Field;
```

Do I have to do my ordering in my scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly query the information schema tables instead.  As the [manual says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html):

> The following statements are nearly equivalent:
>
> ```
> SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
>   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
>   WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
>   [AND table_schema = 'db_name']
>   [AND column_name LIKE 'wild']
>
> SHOW COLUMNS
>   FROM tbl_name
>   [FROM db_name]
>   [LIKE 'wild']
> ```

You can apply an `ORDER BY` clause to the first type of statement, since it is a normal `SELECT` command.

Therefore, in place of your `SHOW` command, you can do:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
      TABLE_NAME = 'TB_Main'
  AND COLUMN_TYPE IN ('mediumtext', 'bit(1)')
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME;
```

Comment: almost, I think you need `AND COLUMN_TYPE IN ('mediumtext', 'bit(1)')` instead of `DATA_TYPE` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86af6/12

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @craniumonempty... but I'm curious: whilst the docs show the `COLUMNS` schema table having both fields, they don't specify what the difference is? ** **EDIT**: Played with your sqlfiddle and I can see that `DATA_TYPE` doesn't include column width, whereas `COLUMN_TYPE` does.  Updated my answer - thanks.